# If they were Vs If They had been

Tags: conditional-constructions

What is the difference between *if they had been* and *If they were*:

> "If Adam and Eve **had been** Chinese we would still be in the paradise because they would have eaten the snake instead of the apple."

Is there any meaning difference if I say?

> "If Adam and Eve **were** Chinese would still be........................"

some more examples

> If I **were** you I would have Vs If I **had been** you I would have
>   If you **were** I you would have Vs if you **had been** I you would have
>   If He **were** we we would have Vs If he **had been** we we would have

Comment: You should read about [conditional sentences](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/conditional-sentences) to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Adam and Eve are long dead, and we are therefore  talking of a past counterfactual situation. We need *If Adam and Eve had been Chinese* (in the past), *we would still be in Paradise* (now), *because they would have eaten...* (in the past).

Similarly, with your other examples, the choice of tenses depends on the time of the counterfactual/hypothetical situations.

You resigned from your job last week.

*If I had been you (last week), I would not have resigned (last week).*

*If I had resigned* (last week), *I would be very worried* (now).

*If I were you* (now), *I would be  very worried about the future* (now).

Comment: I guess the OP is to be more clarified with *subjunctive mood* and *past simple*.

Comment: I am one of those who believes that it is not helpful to claim that modern English has a past subjunctive form. However, as that is not relevant to this particular question, I simply did not mention the subjunctive.